# Using options of different kinds in ps commands

Tags: ps

From the manpage of `ps` from package `procps-ng`

> This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:
>
> 1   UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a
>              dash.
>
> 2   BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a
>              dash.
>
> 3   GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.
>
> Options of different types may be freely mixed, but conflicts can
>          appear.  There are some synonymous options, which are functionally
>          identical, due to the many standards and ps implementations that this
>          ps is compatible with.

I often see within a tutorial article, UNIX options in some commands, BSD options in some commands, GUN options in some commands, and a mix of two or more options in some commands.

In the  implementation of `ps` from package 'procps-ng`,

1. Is using options of different kinds in different or the same commands a good or bad habit?
2. is it necessary to use various kinds of options? If yes, is it because there are some options in one kind which one can't find their equivalents in another kind?

Thanks.

Comment: "is it necessary to use various kinds of options?" - Necessary for what?

Answer (score 2):

ps option parsing is complex. There is actually an environment variable (PS_PERSONALITY) which will change how it parses things as well. I'd suggest to ignore that though.

Most people use either the BSD or Unix variety of flags. You will often see "ps aux" or "ps -ef" for example.

There is no hard and fast rule, choose the style that suits you. Having worked on both Solaris and BSD type systems I have a bad habit of using both or even mixing them up together at times. It works but its not a recommendation of that method.

I would recommend you stick to Unix or BSD keep to one for your day to day stuff and learn about the output format ( -o ) and sort ( k ) output formats. You will still need to remember the process selection part.